# How to extract triggered job name in Jenkins using python

Tags: python, jenkins

I need to extract name of currently running Jenkins build using python script.
Could any one tell me that how can i extract Jenkins Triggered job's name at runtime using python ?

Answer (score 0):

I've never cared about this particular bit of information before, but Jenkins sets up some [environment variables](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) during the build.  So it appears all you need is something like:

```
import os
job_name = os.getenv("JOB_NAME")
```

Depending on your build outside of a Jenkins environment, it might be useful to specify a default in case the variable is not set:

```
job_name = os.getenv("JOB_NAME", "(local build)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Jenkins library in Python](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
import jenkins
build_info = jenkins_client.get_build_info(test_job, <build_number>)
```

Note: `<build_number>` is the job build number for which you want the info.